# Using a WHILE statement to check against duplicates in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to write a program containing 3 String ArrayLists, where 1 item may be included in all 3 ArrayLists. However, the output must insure that the randomly selected items are all different. As I work through this issue, I am just using numbers so it will be easier to catch. I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days now, and figure there must be something I am overlooking. Here is the code for the method that must have the fault:

```
private void generateThree() {
    // Find the maximum number the random can be.
    index = thirdNumberArray.size();
    // Initiate the random function.
    Random rand = new Random();
    // Generate a random number from 1 to the maximum.
    randomInt = rand.nextInt(index);
    // Access the item in the ArrayList using the random number as the index.
    thirdDrawn = thirdNumberArray.get(randomInt);
    // Check that the number is different than any previously set numbers.
    while ((thirdDrawn.equals(secondDrawn)) || (thirdDrawn.equals(firstDrawn))) {
        randomInt = rand.nextInt(index);
        thirdDrawn = thirdNumberArray.get(randomInt);
    }
    // Set the output.
    thirdNumberLabel.setText((thirdDrawn));
    // Reset the index.
    index = 0;
}
```

So far, the IF statement I use to check the secondDrawn against the firstDrawn has worked perfectly. But the above code still allows the thirdDrawn to display a duplicate of both the firstDrawn and secondDrawn. I know this problem has to be in my loop logic, but I just can't grasp what it is. I have tried multiple different IF statements, but they didn't solve the whole problem. Can anyone give me some feedback or corrections? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a Set. Why reinvent it?

Comment: What is the type of `thirdNumberArray` and the other two objects? Is it `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: Here here. A set is much more conducive to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you generate a number you want to draw, add it to a `HashSet<String>`.  Then, have your `if` statement conditional check `!myHashset.contains(thirdDrawn)`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. This not only worked, but I feel it makes the code more clear (no more clanky compound statement). This site is a fantastic resource for us beginners, and I wanted to thank you all for taking the time to help us out.